# Exporting data in grid format splitting the last column

Tags: list-manipulation, export

I have a list of lists, and I displayed it in grid format. The grid is huge, so I will show here an example:

```
list = {{2, 2, 2, {1, 3}}, {2, 1, 2, {1, 2}}, {1, 2, 2, {1, 4}}}
Grid[list, Frame -> All]
```

Now, I would like to export the data in Csv format, so to have 5 variables. What I did so far is:

```
Export["list.csv", list, "CSV"]
```

Problem is that in this way I have only four variables. What I need to do is to "split" the last column in two variables. Indeed, for each row it contains two values.
So, in other words, I need to export a data set with five variables (the first column, the second column, the third column, and the values in the last column).

In another grid I have a similar but more complicated issue. Here it is:

```
list2 = {{2, 2, 2, {{1, 3} , {1, 2}}}, {2, 1, 2, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}}, {1, 2, 2, {1, 4}}}
Grid[list2, Frame -> All]
```

As you can see, here sometimes I have two pairs of solutions in the last columns, sometimes only one. The data set I would like to export from that is similar to the first one. So, the first three variables correspond to the values in the first three columns. Moreover, I would like to extrapolate 4 variables from the last column (if it reports only a pair of solution, the last two variables should have missing values or whatever). 
Can someone help me please?

Bonus question: is it possible to name the columns of the grid, so to export a data set with the first row containing the name of the variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
list = {{2, 2, 2, {1, 3}}, {2, 1, 2, {1, 2}}, {1, 2, 2, {1, 4}}};

listf = Flatten /@ list
(* {{2, 2, 2, 1, 3}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 4}} *)

list2 = {{2, 2, 2, {{1, 3}, {1, 2}}}, {2, 1, 2, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}}, {1, 2, 2, {1, 4}}};

list2f = Flatten /@ list2
(* {{2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 4}} *)

max = Length /@ list2f // Max;

PadRight[#, max, Null] & /@ list2f
(* {{2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2}, {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3}, {1, 2, 2, 1, 4, Null, Null}} *)
```

To add column headings

```
listf // Prepend[{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}]
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfect, thank you!

Comment: @PlasticMan You are welcome, thanks for the accept.